# Regex to Remove (exclude) Input Tag Before String

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove an `input` tag that appears before a specific string. I have a huge string that's comprised of a form/table/tr/td/inputs, over 100 of them. Here's the sample html below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="special" value="123">
...
<tr>
  <td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="extendedeventinfo76022" value="y"> Enable Search
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="extendedeventinfo76006" value="y"> Enable Display 
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="extendedeventinfo76137" checked value="y"> Enable Notes
  </td>
</tr>
...
```

Let's say I want to remove the input tag for the `Enable Display`. So far I can select the enable display, 
`^(.*?(\bEnable Display\b)[^$]*)$` 
but I'm not sure how to go to the previous tag `<input...>` and remove it (or better yet, select the entire document, but excluding those inputs).

I also have *lone* `input` tags that I'll have to remove as well based on what the `name` attribute is. So basically, regex that will give the output below:

```
...
<tr>
  <td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="extendedeventinfo76022" value="y"> Enable Search
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td> 
     Enable Display 
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="extendedeventinfo76137" checked value="y"> Enable Notes
  </td>
</tr>
...
```

As you can see, the first hidden input with name "special" is gone as well as the input next to the words "Enable Display".

Answer (score 0):

Designing a single regex to achieve what you want in one shot, is not quite trivial and will be slow to execute.

You might want to think about alternative approach - looping through the lines/tags (possibly using one of XML/HTML PHP parsers) and construct desired output accordingly to your criteria.

Comment: I'm using Symfony2 to scrape data from a web page. Then I convert the form part to a string, which I need to use regex to exclude certain parts of that string, such as the inputs where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php 
$string = <<<'EOT'
<input type="hidden" name="special" value="123">
...
<tr>
  <td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="extendedeventinfo76022" value="y"> Enable Search
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="extendedeventinfo76006" value="y"> Enable Display 
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="extendedeventinfo76137" checked value="y"> Enable Notes
  </td>
</tr>
...

EOT;
echo preg_replace('/<input .* name="special" .*>|
                    <input .*>(?=\ Enable\ Display)/x', '', $string);
```